# Connecting Arduino Due's DAC output to pc sound card with protection

Tags: arduino-due, digital-analog-conversion

I would like to connect the DAC outputs of my arduino board to my pc sound card input so that I can use my sounds card as an osciloscope.

I have two questions:

1- if I don't use an amplifier,  how can I protect the arduino from being damaged?

2- if I use an amplifier with dual rails,  do i still need to protect the arduino somehow?

Please note that I know little about analog circuitry so a direct solution would be most appreciated. In short how would I use components to make sure I don't end up nuking my dac outputs.

Thanks.

Comment: For audio they generally AC-couple the output. i.e. put a capacitor in series with the DAC output.

Comment: Does any capacitor do? or should I look for specifics?
I know the DAC output will not go over 3.7 volts, in fact it barely reaches that number.

Comment: That not really my area of expertise. Maybe [this question will help](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/audio-ac-coupling-capacitors).